# Cannot open xls file with C# service

Tags: c#, excel, import, excel-interop, interopservices

I have to create a service to import data from an excel file into a SQL Server table; the whole system belongs to one of my company's customer so I must use Visual Studio 2010. Some open may have this file opened so I decided to copy it to a temporary directory and then parse this copy. I thought I made it, since it worked correctly in debug mode: the file is opened, all the lines are read and in the end the values are written in the DB. I installed it as a service but I keep on getting the same error (translated into English):

```
System.Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): impossible access file "C:\[temp dir]\[file.xls]". Possible reasons are:

• file name or path file do not exists.
• file in use by another program.
• the name of the folder/worksheet you are trying to save corresponds to the name of an open folder/worksheet.
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)
```

The file exists, I can find it in the folder, and nobody is using it at the moment the service tries to open it (I just copied it). I am not trying to save it, I open it in read only mode so I can exclude the 3rd point also. 
The machine where I am developing the service is the same machine where the service runs, a Windows 7 Ultimate, Service Pack 1.

I thought it could be a problem of the user of the service, so I tried to launch the service in Visual Studio in debug mode logging to the system with the same user of the service (admin level) and it worked perfectly fine.
Then I thought it could be a problem of timing, maybe the service tried to open the file "too soon" while the system had not released it, so I added a

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

before the

```
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

line but nothing changed.
Of course, everytime I modify the service I stop it, copy the new files to the system and then restart it.

The code is:

```
string fileName = "[file name].xlsm";
string sourcePath = @"[origin]";
string targetPath = @"[destination]";
string fileDest = "[destination file name].xls";
string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
string targetFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileDest);

try
{
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, targetFile, true);
}
catch (Exception myEx)
{
    throw new Exception(myEx.ToString());
}

xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
xlApp.Visible = false;
try
{
    wbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(targetFile, 0, true, Type.Missing, "[pwd]", "[pwd]", true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); [<- this is the problem, the exception is raised with these instruction]
    sheet = new Worksheet();
    range = null;
    sheet = wbk.Worksheets.get_Item(4);
    range = sheet.UsedRange;
    numColonne = range.Columns.Count;
    numRighe = range.Rows.Count;
}
catch (Exception myEx)
{
    throw new Exception(myEx.ToString());
}
```

What can I do to solve this problem?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added these 2 folders, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop (64bit) and C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop (32bit). I found them in an another forum and I decided to try; now it works. 
Don't ask me why...